# Cannot run file in google drive directory (using file syncing) because of white space in 'My Drive'

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua, google-drive-api, love2d

I'm writing a game in Lua using Löve2D using google drive syncing for backup, meaning I am directly editing the file in my drive. This means the file path is "G/My Drive/Truck" (Truck is the name of the game folder). When I open the folder in VS Code it works fine and I can access and edit everything, but when I actually try to run the main.lua with the alt+L command I get this error:

> boot.lua:577: Cannot load game at path 'g:/My'.
> Make sure a folder exists at the specified path.

I'm not sure if it's Löve itself or if it's VS Code which can't cope with the white space.
I have previously accessed, edited and run the file with no issue on a different computer, but am now trying to do so on my laptop, and am encountering this issue.
OS is Windows 11.

I've tried opening "G/My_Drive/Truck" which doesn't work. Since it's google drive I can't just rename it to remove the whitespace.

Comment: How do you construct the string that throws the error? And did you try define long string? Example: ```path = [[G/My Drive/Truck]]``` or ```path = [["G/My Drive/Truck"]]``` or ```path = [['G/My Drive/Truck']]``` or if the string will be URL decoded: ```path = "G/My%20Drive/Truck"```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you've provided, Lua does not receive a full path to your folder, just a small piece: `'g:/My'`

This usually happens when you pass a string that contains a whitespace by command line like this:

`love.exe game.love G:/My Drive/Truck`

How to fix:

`love.exe game.love "G:/My Drive/Truck"`

If that does not help, then post more details: how do you launch it, where path to your gdrive folder is stored.

Comment: I'm opening and running through VS Code by just pressing alt+L. How do I specify the launch path? I tried changing the target program in the launch.json config but that doesn't work.